# Hibernate and struts2 createcriteria

Tags: hibernate

HI,

I have a parent - child relationship and want to query putting a restriction on the child records. I only want to load into the parent records those children that match the criteria. i have tried the below one but getting all records thou it matche or not
:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Activities.class);
Criteria prdCrit = crit.createCriteria("favorites");
prdCrit.add(Restrictions.
    eq("accFavorities","true"));
prdCrit.add(Restrictions.
    eq("compnay","yahoo"));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787002/hibernate-child-collection-limited-when-using-left-join-in-criteria/5391399#5391399)

or use a subquery instead (DetachedCriteria)

Comment: Thanks. I used below query and it worksCriteria crit = session.createCriteria(Activities.class);
   Criteria prdCrit = crit.createCriteria("favorites", "favorites",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
   prdCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("favorites.accFavorities","true"));
   prdCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("favorites.company",userCompany));
   activities = prdCrit.list();